# Is asking "Who is God" too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Who is God? Do all Muslims agree on one definition?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/249/who-what-is-god)

Is this question too broad? Are we going to allow questions like this to be asked on our site?

Answer (score 3):

Asalamu wa alaikum,

These kind of questions are going to end up being asked either on here or somewhere else, it will be better to answer it so that they get answers.  The only thing we can't answer is what is God.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't particularly broad. Asking for a definition of God is fairly central to defining and understanding a religion...I am not sure how this question can be more specific.

There is also nothing wrong with asking about the definition of God and how it applies to a religion. Not all religions define God in a similar manner - in some religions God is a creator, and in some religion God is more like a manager, in some God is a force, in some God is non-existent.

There is nothing wrong with someone asking how a religion perceives God. What is wrong with asking something like this on the website?

Other religion related stackexchange "expert" websites had no problems with questions like these.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong. I asked if it was to broad.

Answer (score -1):

yes it is broad. but anyway it is a question.

Comment: But questions that are too broad are not fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Dynamic why? also people always asked this question form prophet and Imams. also perhaps this is not broad.

Comment: That's SE policy...